# mysql php query HAVING clause

Tags: php, mysql, having, clause

Im trying to get this query to work but i get this error:
Unknown column 'zips.city' in 'having clause'

```
`$query = "SELECT
    zips.*
    FROM
    zips
    HAVING
    zips.city LIKE '%$city%' 
    AND
    zips.stateabbr LIKE '%$state%' 
    LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());`
```

my zips table has a city column, so im not sure what the problem is, i know im accessing the database because i can run this query with no errors:

```
$zip1query = "SELECT 
         zips.*
         FROM 
         zips
         WHERE
         zips.zip = '$zip'              
         ";
```

any advice would be much appreciated! thanks!

Comment: If you use HAVING you need to GROUP BY also.

Comment: Yes, but that will just make the query unnecessarily complicated. Why use both when a simple WHERE will do?

Comment: @Justin: We don't really know what Pete wants though.

Comment: If you still get the error, if means that you don't have a city column in the table

Comment: i don't need to use HAVING i just used it from some old searchquery code that I had, i wasn't sure if you needed to use it with the LIKE command. but anyways i got this error: Unknown column 'zips.city' in 'where clause',

Comment: o jeez sorry guys i figured out the problem, apparently i put a space before city when i named the columns in my table. so i renamed the column and it works thanks anyway chaps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `having` clause doesn't mean the same thing as the `where` clause : when running a simple query, you should use `where` -- which is what you did in your second query, that works.

`having` is used when the condition has to be applied on the result of a `group by` clause.

Which means that, here, your query should be build this way :

```
$query = "SELECT zips.*
    FROM zips
    where zips.city LIKE '%$city%' 
        AND zips.stateabbr LIKE '%$state%' 
    LIMIT 1";
```

With that, if you still have an error about a non-existing or not-found column *(at least for `city` and/or `stateabbr`)*, it'll be because that column doesn't exist in your table.

In this case, there is not much we can do : you'll have to check the structure of your table, to determine which columns it contains.

You can check that structure using a web-based tool like phpMyAdmin, or using an SQL instruction such as :

```
desc zips;
```

For reference, quoting [MySQL's manual page for `select`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) :

> The SQL standard requires that HAVING
>   must reference only columns in the
>   `GROUP BY`  clause or columns used in
>   aggregate functions. 
>  ... 
>   
> Do not use `HAVING` for items that
>   should be in the `WHERE` clause.
>   
> For example, do not write the
>   following:
>
> ```
> SELECT col_name FROM tbl_name HAVING col_name > 0;
> ```
>
> Write this instead:
>
> ```
> SELECT col_name FROM tbl_name WHERE col_name > 0;
> ```
>
> ...
>   
>   The `HAVING` clause can refer to
>   aggregate functions, which the `WHERE`
>   clause cannot

Answer (score 1):

Try using `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`.

Comment: thank you for your help I got this error: Unknown column 'zips.city' in 'where clause',

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it is by using a WHERE clause.

```
$query = "SELECT
zips.*
FROM
zips
WHERE
zips.city LIKE '%$city%' 
AND
zips.stateabbr LIKE '%$state%' 
LIMIT 1";
```

HAVING is to be used when you are GROUPing, see [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3469351/The-HAVING-and-GROUP-BY-SQL-clauses.htm) for an explanation

Answer (score 0):

o jeez sorry guys i figured out the problem, apparently i put a space before city when i named the columns in my table. so i renamed the column and it works thanks anyway chaps! but using the where function instead of having must speed things up alot, thanks guys!